# Why the program pass all tests if I use regular if statement in the method but says `stack level too deep` when using a ternary operator instead?

Tags: ruby, oop, if-statement, ternary-operator, stack-level

I was working on coding challenge called Robot name. I also had tests for that. The program passed all the tests. The code is below..

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :name
  @@robots = []
  def initialize
    @name = self.random_name
    @@robots << self.name
  end

  def random_name
    name = ''
    2.times do
      name  << ('a'..'z').to_a.sample
    end
    3.times do
      name  << (1..9).to_a.sample.to_s
    end
    no_duplicate(name.upcase)
  end

  def reset
    @name = self.random_name
  end

  def no_duplicate(name)
    if @@robots.include? name
      reset
    else
      name
    end
  end
end
```

If you need to see the tests file you can look it up here [robot_name_tests](https://github.com/sashaProdan/weekly_challenges/blob/master/robot_name/robot_name_test.rb%22robot_name_test%22).

Then I started to refactor and one of the first things was to refactor `no_duplicate` method. So after refactoring the code looked like this

```
class Robot

  ...
  # the rest of code stayed the same

  def no_duplicate(name)
    @@robots.include? name ? reset : name
  end
end
```

With this version all tests showed `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. Why does it give this error and what is going on behind the scenes in both cases considering the code provided? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I like your *poetry mode* code but it has led you into trouble here.

One way to kinda keep it in poetry mode but fix your operator priority issue is to do this:

```
   def no_duplicate(name)
     (@@robots.include? name) ? reset : name
   end
```

*Update:* if you work in Big Corporation With Coding Standards you will need to make it a bit more boring. I thought this was obvious but the gallery is correctly noting the usual solution:

```
   @@robots.include?(name) ? reset : name
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks! But why this confused ruby? because of `name`? It doesn't get confused every time when using this type of statement. Why in this case?

Comment: Because the ? : operator bound more closely than the function parameters did. That is, Ruby was evaluating: `@@robots.include?(name ? reset : name)`

Comment: Got it!Thanks for explanation.

Comment: A more idiomatic solution would be to simply use parentheses around the arguments: `@@robots.include?(name) ? ...`

Comment: @Jordan: Yes! Pretty much every question about errors regarding the conditional operator can be answered either with "follow the Ruby Community Style Guide" or "use a conditional expression instead". Which is why I don't get why Rubyists love the conditional operator so much. I find `if @@robots.include? name then reset else name end` much more readable, *and* it has the precedence that everybody expects. The conditional operator is a crutch required in C, because `if` is a statement, not an expression, but in Ruby it *is*, and so the conditional operator is just superfluous.

Comment: @Jordan, I figured that would be obvious. At first glance it looked like she wanted poetry mode.  Since I'm a poetry-mode nut I gave her the kinda-lispy answer.  But, she wasn't consistent about poetry mode so maybe the garden-variety function call is best, sure.

Comment: Nothing is obvious to newcomers, least of all the meaning of jargon like "poetry mode."